# Import model from inside ember-engine

Tags: ember.js, ember-engines

I have an Ember.js application with an ember-engine added as an external addon, and both the parent application and the engine share the store. 
This creates an issue because when fetching a model in a route from the engine, the fact of having the store shared makes the parent application to crash saying that it does not know the model.

Copying the model from inside the engine into the parent's models fixes it, but it goes against the principle of isolation.

I wonder if there is any way of importing an engine's model into the parent application, because even if that also makes the parent aware of the engine's model, at least it won't be replicating code.

Since it is an addon, I supposed this would work:

```
`import DockerComposeModel from 'ember-stack-builder-engine/models/docker-compose'`
```

But throws an error

```
Error: Could not find module `ember-stack-builder-engine/models/docker-compose` imported from `bde-integrator-user-interface/application/controller`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us some code How you are configuring the engine.

normally engine and app shares the model and you do not have to use import.

You can directly use `this.findRecord(ModelName)` but if it does not work then please share your code.

Comment: I have the store shared between the engine and the application. In the application I never try to fetch a model defined in the engine but yet it fails. Nothing special, just adding the store as a shared service.

Comment: What i know so far lookup is one way as in you can inject app service,controllers,routes in engine. lookup from engine to app is not possible as per what i know. 

https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/10/files#r38705032 see this.